# Elastisearch is not treating Unix timestamps as valid timestamps

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following request which is sent to an elasticsearch server like:

http://localhost:9200/myindex/_bulk

However the timestamp is not recognized as the document timestamp and shows up as just any field with a long value.

Elasticsearch docs say that Unix epoch is a standard time format and I don't have to create any special mappings for that.

```
{ "index" : { "_type" : "regionserver.Regions" } }
{ "@timestamp" : 1492012311392, "type" : "regionserver.Regions", "region" : "1588230740", "table" : "meta", "storeCount" : 1, "storeFileCount" : 2, "memStoreSize" : 416, "storeFileSize" : 13453 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have explicit mapping defined for `@timestamp` field as `date` type in order to index `unix timestamp` values otherwise Elasticsearch considers them as `long` type. So before indexing `unix timestamp` values into `@timestamp` field, define mapping as shown below:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "regionserver.Regions": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tried this. I was avoiding having to create mappings for every index and every doctype in that.
Does ElasticSearch allow a global setting where one can map any field named "@timestamp" to be a date?

Comment: I think i'm going to answer my follow up question:

The answer is in templates:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Comment: Yes, Elasticsearch `index templates` does that.